# Determine process id by clicking on the window of the executable in question

Tags: c#, process

can someone give me a clue as to how to accomplish the following:

By clicking on an application's window, I'd like to determine the process id of executable concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fair amount of Win32 API calls required to get this to work in .NET. I would suggest you look at the .NET open source project [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) as it does what you want already.

It is LGPL licensed and provides libraries to include in your project to get it's functionality. From the [FAQ](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/faq.php)

> **I'm a developer. Can I use the various functions provided by Process Hacker
>   in my own program?**
>   If you're using a
>   .NET-based language (C#, VB.NET),
>   absolutely! Simply download the source
>   code (or checkout the latest SVN
>   revision), build the solution, and
>   reference ProcessHacker.Common and
>   ProcessHacker.Native in your project.